# How to find computed size of any element in Chrome Developer Tools?

Tags: css, google-chrome, developer-tools

I'm sure this is somewhere in the developer tools inspector, but I can't find it. Where would I find, for a given element (say, a div), the computed dimensions (height and width) of a given element that I right click on and select "Inspect Element"?

Comment: 'Inspect element,' look at the right hand pane, click on 'computed styles' the top-most panel. Or use the 'metrics' panel. But this is not a programming question, I think.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Just hover over the element name in the ribbon below the developer tools panel. The corresponding element will be highlighted in the browser window and the dimensions appear at a corner of it. Also, if you scroll down the right pane in the developer tools, you'll see the 'Metrics' window which'll give you the computed dimensions and also the margins, paddings, borders etc.

Here's a screenshot of the dimensions of the div that holds your SO question. Notice the dimensions at the bottom left corner of the highlighted region as I hover over the div name at the bottom. On the right is the Metrics window.

[image: Computed Size Screenshot]

[Click here for bigger image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qu6QS.png)

For future questions, just refer to Google's [nice documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools) first.

Comment: Google documentation link is now broken.  Page can now be found at https://developer.chrome.com/devtools

Comment: In version "46.0.2490.86 m", there are no "Computed styles" and the Metrics window says 100% x 100%. :(

Comment: what does it mean on the items that are disabled ? the values are displayed but you can't expand or interact with those particular items.

Comment: how to get it programmatically? using js?

Answer (score 0):

If, like me, you came to this answer looking for a way to output the width of an element in the browser's console, here's that answer:

```
document.querySelector("element_id").clientWidth;
```